# Replace an entire column of a table with a new column in html using a select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I want to replace an entire column of a table with a new column in html using a select option.

```
<select id="time" onchange="changeTest()">
    <option value="us">us</option>
    <option value="ms">ms</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeTest(){
    var selTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var i;
    var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows;//any table for eg
    for(i=1; i<rows.length; i++){
        if(selTime == 'us'){
            rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = "data1";
        }else if(selTime == 'ms'){
            rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = "data2";
        }
    }
}
```

```
<table id = "table" >
    <thead>
        .
        .
        .
    </thead>
    <tbody >

        {section name=id loop=$test}
        {strip}
            .
            .
            .
            <tr>
                .
                .
                .
                <td> {$test[id].t}</td>
                .
                .
                .
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
         {/strip}
         {/section}
     </tbody> 
 </table>
```

In this case:

> data1=$test[id].t
>
> data2=$test[id].t2

In other words, i want to use `$test[id]`.t in javascript.
I tried using `JSON_PARSE`, but it dint work.

Comment: Please show us the current result and the result that you expect.

Comment: currently it shows me "data1" and "data2" on scrolling through the select.
i want it to display $test[id].t and $test[id].t2 depending on the select